# group by where null belong to all groups

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's assume I have following table

```
|     a_id   |  b_id       |   price  |
|      1     |   10        |   100    |
|      1     |   11        |   50     |
|      1     |   NULL      |   300    |
```

and I want group it by a_id and b_id and get the sum of prices, but NULL has to belong to both group.I want get table like this

```
|     a_id   |   price  |
|      1     |  400     |
|      1     |  350     |
```

Any ideas? thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you need that? please explain the context, I think you might do something wrong in the first place

Comment: is a_id indexed?

Comment: @AgapwIesu yes it is primary key, but this table is result of join

Comment: Then you should probably show the layout of the tables themselves, not this join.  Any answer based on you giving us a join, when we think we are looking at a table, is not going to be optimal.

Answer (score 3):

You could use:

```
SELECT a_id,  
  SUM(price) + COALESCE(
           (SELECT SUM(price) FROM tab3 WHERE a_id = t.a_id AND b_id IS NULL),0) 
   AS price
FROM tab3 t
WHERE b_id IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY a_id, b_id;
```

**[Rextester Demo](http://rextester.com/LNWN36279)**

How it works:

- main query do aggregation based on a_id, b_id where b_id IS NOT NULL
- add to result value for b_id IS NULL (correlated subquery)

Comment: Doing a subquery inside a select is not efficient.  The same can be accomplished with a join and will be much more efficient.  Whenever you have a select inside a select, look for a way to do the same with a join.

Comment: Depends on the volume of data and indexes.  mySQL's Cost Based optimizer can do some hinky stuff sometimes for efficiency.

Comment: In this query the subquery will be executed only once per distinct `a_id` and can beat a LEFT JOIN in performance. However - I would also use COALESCE() here for the case that no "group price" exist.

Comment: this solution won't work in case when for particular a_id has in b_id all NULLs [link](http://rextester.com/ABOUX75723)

Comment: @PaulSpiegel - The fact that in this query the subquery gets performed once per record in the outer query is exactly why this query is inefficient.  And no, it does not beat a left join.    In a join (even a LEFT join) both sides of the join get performed only once, period.  Read - https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189575(v=sql.105).aspx.  It will tell you that many times subqueries like this are less efficient than a join (any join - a left join is not less efficient than an inner join), and that whenever possible you should change a subquery for a join.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel - Say you have a table with a million different a_id's.  For each a_id, this query would then again query the whole table.  That is, the million records get queried a million and one times.  Ridiculously inefficient.  With a join, even a left join, the records get queried two times, once for each side of the join.  2 is more efficient than a million and 1 times.  The way my join solution is stated, the record set is queried three times - two for the join, and then another for the outer query.  That is why xQbert's solution is best (2 beats 3 beats 1,000,001).

Comment: @PaulSpiegel - guessing that you would not accept my comments, I created a table with this structure.  I added 400,000 records to it, 200k with unique a_id and unique b_id, 200k with corresponding a_id and null b_id.  I ran the three queries multiple times, interweaving them so that no query got the benefit of preloaded dataset.  This was the least efficient with an average execution time of 2.895 seconds.  xQbert's average execution time 2.701 seconds.  Surprisingly, my solution average execution: 2.078 seconds.

Comment: @AgapwIesu - I wrote "the subquery .. **can** beat a LEFT JOIN", but not "it **will** beat **any** LEFT JOIN in **any** case". And here's the case: 100 distinct A_IDs cross joined with 100 distinct B_IDs - makes 10K groups. 100 entries per group makes 1M rows. And 100 rows per A_ID with B_ID IS NULL. Overall 1010K rows. This query runs in 230 ms with the best index on `(a_id, b_id, price)`. Your query runs in 515 ms with the best index on `(b_id, a_id, price)`. Tested with MariaDB 10.0.19. So my point is - This query is simple, fast anough and in some cases can even outperform other solutions.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel - yes, the way I did the join will start faster, but will be slower than the subquery for much larger datasets.  But if you test the way xQbert did the join, you will find that it is faster in every case, certainly for 1M records, but also for much smaller datasets.  And, if there is no index on a_id, the difference will grow exponentially.  Everything you read will tell you that an IN clause with a subquery really is "the worst thing you can do".

Comment: @AgapwIesu xQberts 2nd query has a runtime of 765 ms on my dataset. The reason is the group size (100 in my case and 1 in your case). The 1st query timed out.

Answer (score 2):

You could split the data into two different subsets then add.

So set A consists of only those records where B_ID is not null.
   set B consists of only those records where B_ID is null

The risk this has is that if a a_ID could have multiple NULL B_ID's then the join would result in a many to many and the sum will be wrong.  If B_ID is null for only 1 A_ID then this works.

```
SELECT A.a_ID, A.B_ID, sum(A.Price+coalesce(B.Price,0)) price
FROM tab3 A
LEFT JOIN tab3 B
  on A.A_ID = B.A_ID
 and B.B_ID is null
WHERE A.B_ID is not null
GROUP BY A.A_ID, A.B_ID
```

Tested using lad2025's [rextester demo](http://rextester.com/RJDJ66880)

If However, we have multiple NULL B_IDs for an A_ID then we need to total before the join in a subquery.   Such as in this http://rextester.com/PNV55958

```
SELECT A.a_ID, A.B_ID, sum(A.Price+coalesce(B.Price,0)) price
FROM tab3 A
LEFT JOIN (SELECT SUM(Price) Price, A_ID 
           FROM tab3 
           WHERE B_ID is null 
           GROUP BY A_ID) B
  on A.A_ID = B.A_ID
WHERE A.B_ID is not null
GROUP BY A.A_ID, A.B_ID
```

Comment: `a_id` is ambiguous

Comment: I think this will work, and is probably the most efficient solution.  And nice catch with the COALESCE.

Comment: it does but it needs a coalesce(b.price,0) if there are situations where NULL is not existant for a A_ID  I knew I needed that left join... maybe... knew.  maybe the data doesn't exist that way who knows! edge case testing for the loss!

Comment: Also note: that if multiple nulls exist in a B_ID for a given A_ID then we have to sum before the join or the M:M relationship will cause the price  result to be inflated.

Comment: In case when a_id has only NULL for b_id it does not work, because a_id value is different in subquery and does not match [link](http://rextester.com/NUEY42092)

Comment: Example please.

Comment: @NirNor this is why you should have created an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in your question.

Comment: @nirnor what would be the expected result here? A_ID 2, B_ID NULL and 40?

Comment: @PaulSpiegel - I did more testing.  I added 2 million records to a test table.  1M with unique a_id and unique b_id, and 1M with corresponding a_id and null b_id.  I ran queries for the first 100k a_id, then the first 200k, then the first 300k, and so on.  Every single time xQbert's solution outperformed the other solutions here, except for a smaller dataset (200k records) where my solution did better.  A join like xQbert has done here will always outperform a query with subquery like lad2025 had.  In every single test I ran, it was at least 10% faster.  Nir Nor, this is your answer.

Comment: @xQbert - yes, it has group first by a_id then by b_id if b_id is NULL it means that it belong to all group of a_id.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this

```
select a_id, nonnullsums.sum1 + coalesce(nullbidsums.sum2, 0) from
(select a_id, sum(price) as sum1
 from mytable
 where b_id is not null
 group by a_id, b_id) as nonnullsums
left join
(select a_id, sum(price) as sum2
 from mytable
 where b_id is null 
 group by a_id) as nullbidsums
on nonnullsums.a_id = nullbidsums.a_id
```

This does the two sums separately, and then aggregates them.  You could do the same by doing a subquery for each a_id to add in the sum of the nulls, but that would be less efficient.

Comment: What if in the group based on `a_id` there is no corresponding `NULL` value? Row will be skipped with `INNER JOIN`. **[Demo](http://rextester.com/XSXKJT67172)**

Comment: @lad2025 -  Corrected with xQbert's coalesce idea.

Comment: Great :)  Please swap also WHERE with GROUP BY lines and it will work.

Comment: Regarding performance: A LEFT JOIN with a subquery is one of the worst things you can do.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel - "left join with a subquery" - what do you mean?  First, a subquery by definition is in the where or having clause of a select statement (see https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189575(v=sql.105).aspx).  Second, care to specify where you get the idea that a left join, in a statement like this would be "one of the worst things you can do".  You really have no basis for that opinion.

Comment: What I mean is that a subquery generates a temporary table. And you have no controll of how that table is indexed. So in worst case you would have a JOIN which is not supported by an index. However - in your case MySQL seems to return a table with an index on `a_id`, which you need for the JOIN. So your query performs well in my tests, and thus I revoke my first comment and give you an upvote. Though I still prefer lads solution.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel Then you should have said that joining to a query (inner, left, or any kind of join) can be inefficient for larger datasets, because of the absence of index. That would have been correct.  But for smaller datasets, this can be more efficient than even xQbert's join which is best solution. In my test with total 200k records, this query was faster. When the join can be done in memory (smaller sets), a join to a result set will often outperform a result set from a join. In any case, a join like xQbert did will outperform both.

Comment: An INNER JOIN is different because the engine may reverse the JOIN order for a better idex usage.